# Matlab: Saving the filenames of files with specific extension, contained in a folder

Tags: matlab, csv, directory, filenames

I'm working on a funcion to plot the data of many .csv files contained on the same folder. To do it automatically, I want to save the filenames as a string array but the only function I know I can use to get the list of files is dir and by doing

```
x = dir('MyFolder')
```

I get a struct array, not a string or char or whatever array instead. Then, I tried to save on another variable only the first column (from the 3rd row to the end) of the struct array because the filenames lay there, but I get the same struct without the first two rows.

How would you do to solve it? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read this tutorial: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-multiple-elements-of-a-nonscalar-struct-array.html

Comment: That's what I need, thank you @CrisLuengo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files = dir('*.csv') ;   % this gives all csv files present in folder 
N = length(files) ;  % total number of files in the folder 
for i = 1:N 
    thisfile = files(i).name ; 
end
```

In the above *files* is a structure, it has all the information of your csv files. You can extract name of the files using *files(i).name* where i = 1,2,...N. 
If you want all the names of a file in a string. Use

```
filenames = {files.name}' ;
```

Above line, gives you names of all csv files in the folder into a cell array.

Comment: After applying your tip,
`
csvfiles = struct2table(dir('*.csv'));  % Gets all csv filenames
filenames = csvfiles.name;  % Chooses only the names column
filenames = string(filenames);  % Converts data into strings
`
It converts to String in order to let data be used in a simply way by the other functions. The way you did the assigns helped to improve a lot my code's eficiency!